# Which expression to get the elasticsearch client in mvel script

Tags: elasticsearch, mvel

I try to access to an instance of "org.elasticsearch.client.Client" in a mvel script into elasticsearch. I try to call directly "client", and i have this error :

```
[Error: unresolvable property or identifier: client]
```

Apparently is not the good way but i don't see anywhere the good way. But this client exist during the execution of the mvel script, so where can i get it?

Comment: It could be important but the mvel script is stored in file and i call it during query search (but i have potentialy the same trouble during an index phase)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client object is not available in the context of script execution.

Comment: Ok, that why! I actually try to create a transportclient, i think is the best way to have a client in the script.

Comment: Now you made me curious about what you would like to do in a script with a client...and where are you placing that script exactly? Can you elaborate a bit more, maybe updating your question?

Comment: It's a little particular, the goal is to make some calcul during indexation phase and to store the result of this operation in other index in elasticsearch. A bit complex apparently, but it could be work. I don't think an update is efficient, I make a new thread if necessary.